# Step by step instructions on how to remove grub2 or mount the EFI partition and delete files (UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, uninstall

everyone very sorry if this is a duplicate question however I cannot seem to get the instructions on other questions to work. I have been trying to uninstall grub and Ubuntu. I have looked at a lot of Guides.  Most of them say I have to delete the Linux partitions, mount the fat-32 EFI partition and delete the grub files.  I have deleted the Ubuntu partitions, however I can’t get the EFI partition to mount and I don’t know if I would know what to delete even if I did.
Here’s what I have

1. A Manjaro Linux flash drive.
2. A Linux Secure remix bootable flash drive
3. A windows 8 recovery drive
4. Access to windows 8 though a very roundabout way in my BIOS boot menu.
5. [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv0pq9mu28fbldx/Screenshot%202014-11-23%2014.55.07.png?dl=0) is a picture of my partitions(the empty space is where Ubuntu used to be)
6. Grub 2 in recovery mode
   If anyone could give me instructions on how to remove grub2 without re-installing windows in UEFI it will be much appreciated.
   P.S. I have a limited knowledge of partitioning and now almost nothing about terminal commands so please make you instructions as easy to follow as possible.
   Edit 1 I have fast boot and secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to windows , and open cmd.exe as administrator , execute `mountvol S: /S` then `taskkill explorer.exe` then `explorer.exe` then go to my computer , get in to the volume labeled as `S:` look for `grubx64.efi` or something like that and delete it

Comment: I did what you said but when I tried to open disk S: this came up [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzo2uaro9z3y2ys/Screenshot%202014-11-23%2016.58.43.png?dl=0)

Comment: the trick is to open the explorer.exe with administrator rights, if you don't you get that messages, try to open a `cmd.exe` as administrator, then close the explorer.exe using `Taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe` and reopen it from within the command prompt using `explorer.exe` that way you will achieve your goal, good luck :)

Comment: **For People reading later.** So a step by step guide would be 1. Delete the Ubuntu partitions from Windows by using the windows partition manager (this can be found by hitting the windows key and the Q key, typing in Partition and clicking The Create and format hard disk partitions option)    2. Then take the steps above to get in to the EFI partition 3. While in the EFI Partition delete the Ubuntu folder (if you have run boot repair you may have to delete more files look at another post for more information   remove Grub from the boot options 4. Reboot